# CodeMirror UnFold using JQuery

Tags: jquery, codemirror, jquery-events

[Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/hello-world-c/problem):

[image]

How to click the blue arrow which is a span tag using jquery?

```
   $('.CodeMirror-foldmarker').click()
   $('.CodeMirror-foldmarker').trigger('click')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror.foldCode(0,null,'unfold')
```